# Excel Conditional SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel

Consider the following:

```
    A    B    C
----------------
1   a    c    1
2   b    f    2
3   a    c    3
...
6   a    c    4
```

The goal here is to use a conditional SUMPRODUCT so that when the values in row 6 match values in their respective column, the SUMPRODUCT is computed. Here is the interesting thing.

When using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A5=A1),(B3:B5=B1),C3:C5)
```

the input arguments are evaluated as:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({TRUE, FALSE, TRUE},{TRUE, FALSE, TRUE},{1, 2, 3})
```

but the result is 0.

Now when casting the boolean TRUEs and FALSEs to their 1 and 0 counterparts 'before' evaluation of the formula with a mathematical operator, the proper result populates:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A5=A1),--(B3:B5=B1),C3:C5)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A3:A5=A1),ABS(B3:B5=B1),C3:C5)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A5=A1)^2,(B3:B5=B1)^2,C3:C5)
```

etc...,

eventually evaluates to 1s and 0s once the mathematical operator is applied,

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1, 0, 1},{1, 0, 1},{1, 2, 3})
```

and we get the proper value.

We having been racking our minds over Excel can't seem to properly evaluate it's own inputs. We think there is a line of code missing the the SUMPRODUCT compiled code that converts the TRUEs and FALSEs to 1 and 0 and error trapping simply returns a 0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can provide a bit more detail about what you are doing and maybe an example spreadsheet I can help you. We use sumproduct() in almost all our workbooks at work.

Comment: The various things that work for you are coercing Trues and Falses to 1s and 0s by performing an operation on them.  You could also do `=SUMPRODUCT((A3:A5=A1)*(B3:B5=B1),C3:C5)` and it would work.

Comment: Agree with coercing to 1s and 0. I want to understand why I must coerce to 1s and 0s first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most functions don't coerce logical values to numbers in array arguments, and IMHO it's preferable to err on the side of consistency rather than introducing new behavior for a few functions. Coercion also has a performance overhead associated so should only be implemented when needed.

That said some extra functions like `AVERAGEA`, `VARA`, etc. were added that do treat logical values as numbers (and text values as zero) so i guess a SUMPRODUCTA function could have been added too but that might also add confusion and to application bloat. I believe the purpose of these was for compatablity with Lotus 123. There is also a setting for *Transition Formula Evaluation* in *Excel Options | Advanced*, which when activated will treat TRUE/FALSE as numbers in calculations like `SUM` but many functions don't seem to respond to this as expected.

Comment: We had an interview where we asked how to do a conditional sumproduct. He used the -- which intrigued us and led to a 1.5 hour investigation. That investigation led to our question.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked around, and even on Charles Williams' site don't find an answer to why it works this way.  I think it was a programming choice that in its original "native" (all comma) form Sumproduct only operates on numerals, and treats any non-numeric cell as zero.

That way a Sumproduct formula in A1 that references B1:C3 treats TRUE in B1 the same as "strimp099," - as a zero.  I think this makes sense given the original, fairly pedestrian, intent of Sumproduct, and given what an average user might expect as a result.

[image]